# For 1 domain, how can I use both WordPress and Rails?

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, debian-squeeze

I have Rails installed for `example.com`, however, I want to use WordPress for my blog as well. So I want `example.com/blog` to be WordPress. The problem is, I want to have WordPress in a separate directory from the Rails, such as `/srv/www/example-wp` and have Rails in `/srv/www/example-ruby`. How can I separate this? I think it has something to do with virtual hosts, but I am unsure how this is supposed to work.

**Update:**

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
     ServerAdmin support@example.com
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias www.example.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/example-ruby/public/

Alias /blog /srv/www/example-wp/public/

<Directory /srv/www/example-wp/public/>
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

     <Directory /srv/www/example-ruby/public/>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are looking for the "Alias" function in Apache.**

The Alias function allows you to "map" users to a sub-directory outside of the document root.

You would use it like so:

```
Alias /blog /srv/www/example-wp
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: I tried adding that to my virtual hosts, but when visiting the URL, Rails just says  The page you are looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: @Doug Make sure that mod_alias is enabled...  "a2enmod alias"

Comment: It says already enabled, and I even did `apache2 -M` to make sure it's enabled. Is there something I could have missed?

Comment: I see that my phpmyadmin Alias is working, but not the one I setup. Is there any reason why it might not work with ServerName or in the sites-available directory?

Comment: I figured it out. You HAVE to use `PassengerEnabled off` in the directory when using Alias in Apache. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @Doug I've never heard of "PassengerEnabled," is that related to Rails?

Comment: In short yes. Phusion Passenger is needed for Apache for Rails to work.

Answer (score 0):

Alias isn't enough on its own ... the home page and Dashboard work, but no actual post URLs. AliasMatch is required.

```
Alias /blog /var/www/mpblog
AliasMatch /blog/(.*)$ /var/www/wordpress
```

via [Yii2x](https://yii2x.com/running-both-wordpress-and-yii2/)